# using docker programmatically and capturing the standardoutput

Tags: c#, docker

I would like to run some docker commands programmatically inside a process, and capture the standard output of docker. The commands do run without problems, but I cannot capture the standard output. For example, consider the following code. I would like to the read the docker info command, but all I get is a null string. Do you if there is a way to interact with docker in this way? Thanks

```
    private static void VerifyDocker()
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var messagesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var arguments = "info --format '{{json .}}'";

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            processStartInfo.FileName = "docker";
            processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => messagesBuilder.Append(e.Data);
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.CancelOutputRead();

            var message = messagesBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does docker write to stdout, or stderr?  You should also capture stderr (`processStartInfoRedirectStandardError` and `process.ErrorDataReceived`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a good idea to capture both, and also use double quotes instead of single quotes for the parameter passed to --format.

```
    private static void VerifyDocker()
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var messagesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var errorMessagesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var arguments = "info --format \"{{json .}}\"";

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            processStartInfo.FileName = "docker";
            processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => messagesBuilder.Append(e.Data);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => errorMessagesBuilder.Append(e.Data);
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.CancelOutputRead();
            process.CancelErrorRead();

            var message = messagesBuilder.ToString();
            var errrors = errorMessagesBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will this keep the control characters for colorization of the output?